# How to deploy a Realm Object Server

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm looking into using the new Realm Mobile Platform for a project of mine. I've gone through the guides and was able to get it up and running locally no problem. My question is, what's the best way to deploy the Realm Object Server so it can be run remotely? I read through the guide found [here](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#install-realm-object-server) but didn't really understand it. I only have minimal experience deploying a rails app to heroku. How can I get it deployed to Heroku or a similar service? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record: it's incredibly easy to do this: (1) click here https://realm.io/docs/realm-mobile-platform/install-realm-object-server/ (2) click the "AWS/AMI" tab.  Using your free account on AmazonAWS, you're about four clicks away from having a R.O.S. instance running, completely free for moderate use.  (About the only tip is, on one of the three or so setup screen for the EC2, Amazon asks you which OS you want: be careful to choose "Ubuntu 16.04" (not the other Ubuntu).) Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I've followed all Fattie steps.  And now, are the server supposed to be pre installed?  I just cannot see the files.
In other from, is installed from AMI, do I have to di these steps?
# Setup Realm's PackageCloud repository
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/realm/realm/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

# Update the repositories
sudo apt-get update

# Install the Realm Object Server
sudo apt-get install realm-object-server-developer

# Enable and start the service
sudo systemctl enable realm-object-server
sudo systemctl start realm-object-server

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's hard to tell you what the "best" way is. There are always drawbacks and benefits to any setup, and everyone has different goals and objectives, so I don't think there is an objective "best way to run it," as you say.

The Realm Object Server doesn't support Heroku for the time being (or at least, no easy one-click-install integration). We know that this is something that people want, so it's on our radar, but I can't give you a definite answer as to when or even if we will do this one day.

The way most people run the Object Server is by running a virtual machine, and running the service inside of that. There are multiple ways to achieve this: start a virtual machine with your favourite cloud provider, and then install the Realm Object Server on top of that. Alternatively, Realm also provides an AMI image, which is Amazon lingo for "a pre-configured virtual machine image," that contains the Object Server pre-installed, and allows you to run your Object Server at the click of a button.

Please bear in mind that Realm Object Server is currently packaged for RHEL/CentOS 6 & 7, and Ubuntu 16.04.

Here are some links that should help you get started:

- A basic tutorial on how to [setup Ubuntu 16.04 on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04)
- AWS' documentation on [launching an EC2 instance from an AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html)

Comment: thank you @teotwaki, that is helpful! I haven't worked with virtual machines before and didn't really understand what I didn't know. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @teotwaki An option to deploy Realm to Heroku would be great. Hopefully it will happen in the near future.

Comment: @wigging If you want, you can create an issue on our public issue tracker, so that we know what people want: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues

Comment: @teotwaki Great idea, I posted the request on GitHub.

Comment: Found this thread while trying to see if realm can be deployed on Azure. Is there an azure image?

Comment: Please create your own question instead of hijacking other discussions. This being said, no, we don't provide that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this image to run realm-objserct server on openshift online. 
https://hub.docker.com/r/viksgyl/realm-object-server/

Comment: This seems like more of a followup comment, you should put a full answer here to explain what you are referring to.